# Best place to declare own settings so I can access them from sbt shell and my .sbt and .scala build files?

Tags: sbt

[image: sbt shell can't find setting]

My settings are declared in `project/Utils.scala` in an object `BuildSupport` and are made available in `.sbt` and `.scala` files with `import BuildSupport._`.
However, this doesn't work for sbt shell as seen in above screenshot since I can't import them there. For completeness sake, I have tried `eval import BuildSupport._` but all that got me was `<eval>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression`.

How do I have to define own settings and tasks so I can access them from:

- `project/*.scala`,
- `*.sbt` and
- sbt shell?

I assume defining them in an AutoPlugin would work, but I'd rather not have to go to that length. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring an adhoc AutoPlugin (https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html) is the way to go.

Auto plugins ...

- can define `autoImport` object, which is automatically included into `build.sbt`. This can be used for keys.
- can define `globalSettings`, `buildSettings`, or `projectSettings` to inject settings and tasks either at the build-level or at the subproject level. This should become available in sbt shell.

A plugin doesn't have to be a published on its own. You can declare one inside `project/*.scala` like any other Scala object.

The plugin in the linked documentation is great for copy-pasting:

```scala
package sbthello

import sbt._
import Keys._

object HelloPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  override def trigger = allRequirements

  object autoImport {
    val helloGreeting = settingKey[String]("greeting")
    val hello = taskKey[Unit]("say hello")
  }

  import autoImport._
  override lazy val globalSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    helloGreeting := "hi",
  )

  override lazy val projectSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    hello := {
      val s = streams.value
      val g = helloGreeting.value
      s.log.info(g)
    }
  )
}
```